# Why does sort/4 behave this way?

Tags: swi-prolog

I needed to sort a list of three element sublists by their third element. I used sort/4 and it raised a weird error. So I read the [documentation](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/4), had no clue what I did wrong and then tried it on a [simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE6bj.png). The error persisted.

Here are the queries I executed in the screenshot:

```
X = [ [1,2,3], [4,1,5], [3,5,2] ], sort( 2, @<, X, Y ).
X = [ [1,2,3], [4,1,5], [3,5,2] ], sort( 3, @<, X, Y ).
```

The first one succeeds, the second one raises an "argument `3' does not exist in [1,2,3] ..." error. My SWI-Prolog is "(threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.4)".

P.S. No rush, I rearrenged the lists (no bother, really) and it works just fine. Still curious tho, what did I misunderstand?

Edit:

Also, sorting two element sublists by their second element doesn't raise an error. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mkIa.png) and the query:

```
X = [ [1,2], [4,1], [3,5] ], sort( 2, @<, X, Y ).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list, which is a *compound* term, only have two *arguments* (the list head and the list tail), not to be confused with the list *elements*. The following `arg/3` queries should help understand that error:

```
?- arg(1, [1,2,3], Arg1).
Arg1 = 1.

?- arg(2, [1,2,3], Arg2).
Arg2 = [2, 3].

?- arg(3, [1,2,3], Arg3).
false.
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!